# Spring Zuul - throws connection refused

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I'm running a simple example to give a try on Zuul and I just want to redirect my call to google for now.

For it, I have created an Application and annotated with @EnableZuulProxy:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy

@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
class MyApp

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<MyApp>(*args)
}
```

And I have defined an application.properties inside `/resources`:

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled: false
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000

ribbon.ConnectTimeout=3000
ribbon.ReadTimeout=60000

zuul.routes.proxy.path=/google/**
zuul.routes.proxy.url=https://www.google.com/
```

When I hit in my browser a call like `http://localhost:8080/google/search?q=any value`, I got an exception:

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.handleException(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:261) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.SimpleHostRoutingFilter.run(SimpleHostRoutingFilter.java:241) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:126) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140) ~[na:na]
```

Any idea? How can I debug my code?

Answer (score 0):

my Zulu's application.properties are

```
zuul.routes.books.url=http://localhost:8090
zuul.routes.books.path=/student/**
ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
server.port=8080
```

when I want hit any API on the student my URL will be

```
http://localhost:8080/books/student/getStudent
```

so can you try hitting the URL

```
http://localhost:8080/proxy/google/search?q=any value
```